# Failing to remove installed package, apt-get says not installed

Tags: apt

apt list says I have samba

I don't believe I have a need for Samba. I'd like to remove it. But apt-get remove says not installed

```
$ apt list -a samba  
Listing... Done
samba/xenial-updates,xenial-security 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.8 amd64
samba/xenial 2:4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 

$ sudo apt-get remove samba  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'samba' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 19 not to upgrade.
```

Is it possible that it is included not in its own right, but because something else depends on it?

Comment: What is the output of the command `dpkg -l | grep samba` ?

Comment: ii  python-samba      2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.8     amd64        Python bindings for Samba
ii  samba-common      2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.8     all          common files used by both the Samba server and client
ii  samba-common-bin  2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.8     amd64        Samba common files used by both the server and the client
ii  samba-libs:amd64  2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.8     amd64        Samba core libraries

Answer (score 4):

Your `apt list` command does not indicate that samba is installed, just that it is available. Try

`apt list --installed samba`

or

`apt-cache policy samba`

Comment: samba:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.8
  Version table:
     2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.8 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     2:4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

Comment: OK. Next question. Given that it's not installed, why did Software Updater want to update it?

Comment: That would be a valid question, try `apt list --installed *samba*` to see what, containing the same samba, is installed.

Comment: It seems it's needed by a couple of things, including nautilus. (according to: apt list --installed `apt-cache rdepends samba | grep "  "`) 
I'm pretty sure I do want Nautilus. 
A quick search for "Nautilus without Samba" doesn't show anything. I'll start a new question. Be right back.

Comment: That's confusing - I am a novice at regex, but I don''t know why that would have matched 'nautilius'

Comment: 'nautilus-share' does use samba, but my experience has been that samba is uninstalled until sharing is activated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61814/discussion-between-ben-aveling-and-charles-green).